# unable to add buttons vertically

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, grid-layout, gridbaglayout

I am writing a program where JButtons are added dynamically to a JPanel in a vertical fashion. (the buttons are stored in an arraylist)I have tried the following code by setting the JPanel to gridbaglayout.

```
        for(int i = 0; i<listOfButtons.size();i++) {
            c.gridx=0;
            c.gridy=i;
            leftButtonPanel.add(listOfButtons.get(i));
        }
```

the result is the following

[image]

and after adding the buttons

[image]

I have also tried setting the JPanel to a gridlayout

```
leftButtonPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(listOfButtons.size(),1));
```

```
for(int i = 0; i<listOfButtons.size();i++) {
            leftButtonPanel.add(listOfButtons.get(i));
}
```

[image: before adding]

[image]

The buttons "see all" and "add" are all in the same listOfButtons arraylist. and the only way to add buttons into the panel is through that forloop. for some reasons the buttons still start off horizontally.

Comment: When using the GridBagLayout, you must specify the GridBagConstraints instance as the second parameter in the panel.add method.

Comment: OMG yes thats what I was missing thank you so much

Comment: You could just use an Box Layout along the Y axis for this purpose. There would be no need for constraints then cause grid bag seems like overkill

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `GridBagLayout`, don't forget, you need to supply the `GridBagConstraints` as well, otherwise it act a lot like a `FlowLayout`

[image: Water fall]

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class SoTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new SoTest();
    }

    public SoTest() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        public TestPane() {
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
            gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;

            List<JButton> listOfButtons = new ArrayList<>(5);
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                listOfButtons.add(new JButton(Integer.toString(i)));
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < listOfButtons.size(); i++) {
                add(listOfButtons.get(i), gbc);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

At this point, I'm curious as to if you should be considering a `JList` instead